# Добавить модель в класс

Tags: python, django

Могу я в Джанго во вьюху в класс предать ещё одну модель? Я создал сперва посты(модель и класс во вьювс) и отображаю на HTML, но я создал в этом штмл ещё вкладку и хочу из другой модели предавать. Могу ли как-то или через метод или ещё как-то сделать это?

```
class ShowNewsView(ListView):
    model = News
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'news'
    ordering = ['-date']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(ShowNewsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['title'] = "Main page"
        return ctx


class ShowBooksView(ListView):
    model = Book
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'books'
    ordering = ['-date']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(ShowBooksView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['title'] = "Main page"
        return ctx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в методе `get_context_data`
получи требуемый тебе объект и передай его в контекст, по аналогии с тем как ты это делаешь c `title`